# Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, audio

All I want to do is to make the code below more compressed, because i have hundreds of words to vocalize.

```
<audio id="aufgabe" preload="auto">
        <source src="../../../audio/aufgabe.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
    <button id="idj-play-button" class="btn btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></button>
    <button id="idj-pause-button" class="btn btn-xs hide"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></i></button>


<script>
    $('#idj-play-button').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('aufgabe').play();
        $('#idj-play-button').addClass('hide');
        $('#idj-pause-button').removeClass('hide');

    });

    $('#idj-pause-button').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('aufgabe').pause();
        $('#idj-pause-button').addClass('hide');
        $('#idj-play-button').removeClass('hide');
    });

    $('#aufgabe').on('ended', function() {
        $('#idj-pause-button').addClass('hide');
        $('#idj-play-button').removeClass('hide');
        $('#aufgabe').load();
    });

</script>
```

I have almost zero knowledge in javascript so I was wondering is there any way to make some kind of function, for example:

```
function vocalizeFile(aufgabe);
```

that leads to the other functions

```
<script>
    $('#idj-play-button').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('aufgabe').play();
        $('#idj-play-button').addClass('hide');
        $('#idj-pause-button').removeClass('hide');

    });

    $('#idj-pause-button').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('aufgabe').pause();
        $('#idj-pause-button').addClass('hide');
        $('#idj-play-button').removeClass('hide');
    });

    $('#aufgabe').on('ended', function() {
        $('#idj-pause-button').addClass('hide');
        $('#idj-play-button').removeClass('hide');
        $('#aufgabe').load();
    });

</script>
```

so I dont have to make copy of this code everytime.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the event creating a custom data attribute and attaching a click event to it:

HTML:

```
<audio id="aufgabe" preload="auto">
     <source src="../../../audio/aufgabe.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<button id="idj-play-button" class="btn btn-xs" data-action="play" data-target="#aufgabe">
Play
</button>
<button id="idj-pause-button" class="btn btn-xs hide" data-action="pause" data-target="#aufgabe">
Pause
</button>
```

jQuery:

```
  $('body').on('click','[data-action]',function() {
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    switch(action) {
      case 'play': 
            $(target)[0].play();
      break;
      case 'pause':
            $(target)[0].pause();
      break;
    }
    console.log('Called action ',action,' on element ',target);
  });
```

This way you just have to add `data-action=[action-name]` and `data-target=#idOfTarget` to each button and they'll work on any valid `<audio>` element with the specified id.

Comment: That works great, @devJunk, but the button stays only on "play", they are not switching after click.

Comment: You would have to add in the on-off behaviour. I was just laying out the general idea for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $play = $('#idj-play-button');
var $pause = $('#idj-pause-button');
var $aufgabe = $('#aufgabe');

$play.click(playAudio);

$pause.click(pauseAudio);

$aufgabe.on('ended', onEnd);

var toggleButtons = function() {
    $play.toggleClass('hide');
    $pause.toggleClass('hide');
}

var playAudio = function() {
    $aufgabe.play();
    toggleButtons();
}

var pauseAudio = function() {
    $aufgabe.pause();
    toggleButtons()
}

var onEnd = function() {
    $aufgabe.load();
    toggleButtons();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just compressed your code and now it looks like this:

```
var $play = $('#idj-play-button');
var $pause = $('#idj-pause-button');
var $aufgabe = $('#aufgabe');

$play.on('click', function() {
    playAudio();
    toggleButtons();
});

$pause.on('click', function() {
    pauseAudio();
    toggleButtons();
});

$aufgabe.on('ended', function() {
    loadAudio();
    toggleButtons();
});

var toggleButtons = function() {
    $play.toggleClass('hide');
    $pause.toggleClass('hide');
}

var playAudio = function() {
    $aufgabe.play();
}

var pauseAudio = function() {
    $aufgabe.pause();
}

var loadAudtion = function() {
    $aufgabe.load();
}
```

At first, I've cached all elements... If your variable contains an element, I recommend that you start it with `$`, because it says us that the variable is a jquery-element.

If you need to add class and then remove it, you should use `toggleClass`.

The code that manipulates with audio was divided by functions, because we need to maintain one level of abstructions.